# How do I count the messages of Postfix's mailq?

Tags: linux, centos, email, postfix

How can I get number of messages count in Postfix's mailq? `mailq` command display entire mails in mailq but i would like to know **count** only.Is there any command for this. My OS is centos 5.5.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use this:

```
mailq | grep -c "^[A-F0-9]"
```

You can pipe the output of `mailq` through various other filters such as `uniq`, `sort` and `wc` to get other statistics.

Comment: This is not  accurate. When the Postfix queue is empty, then run 'mailq', we will get "Mail queue is empty" which also match "^[0-9A-Z]". And in such a situation it is not accurate.

Comment: A better regex is `^[A-F0-9]` which correctly results in 0 when the mail queue is empty.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: How silly, the last line of the output is the count

Answer (score 17):

either `mailq | tail -n 1` or `find /var/spool/postfix/deferred -type f | wc -l`

both works

Comment: I get "682430 Kbytes in 26472 Requests." for the first one and "23" for the second one.

Comment: The second one only shows deferred messages, adding the active queue the counts should match up: `find /var/spool/postfix/active /var/spool/postfix/deferred -type f | wc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the ouput to wc, if further refining is required, use grep.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
/usr/sbin/postqueue -p | /usr/bin/tail -n1 | /usr/bin/gawk '{print $5}'
```

seems quicker than grep but no 0 returns

Answer (score 0):

I use:

> mailq | grep -c "^$"

This is essentially the same as @Ladadadada's answer of:

> mailq | grep -c "^[A-F0-9]"

Except I am just looking for the empty lines which follow each message entry in the mailq log, rather than something that looks like the start of a valid message-ID. It is therefore better performance-wise, although the difference is only noticeable on very a-typical mailq log sizes.